# How do I preserve text objects in a Matlab axes window when opening a new image?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

My program opens an image

```
pic_handle = imshow('pic.bmp');
```

Then it adds some text objects

```
text(x, y, 'my text');
text(x2, y2, 'more text');
```

Then later on the user can select another image to open which leads to

```
imshow('pic2.bmp');
delete(pic_handle);
```

And now all my text disappears. After poking around a bit, I see that the display list has been cleared and the handles to the text objects seem to be invalid (not fully sure of that).

My question is whether there is some way to preserve the text? ie, open a new image in the axes object without blowing away the display list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. The second `imshow` removes the text (`hold on` fixes it)
2. The new image is placed over the text. This problem can be solved using `uistack`:

   ```
   pic_handle = imshow('pic1.bmp');
   h1=text(100, 20, 'my text');
   h2=text(20, 100, 'more text');
   hold on
   imshow('pic2.bmp');
   delete(pic_handle);
   uistack(h1,'top')
   uistack(h2,'top')
   ```

Comment: shortly after posting it dawned on me that "hold on" would do the trick, as you suggest. Interestingly, the new image is *not* placed over the text. The uistack commands are not needed. I'm not even sure they would work in this context, because the issue is the display order of the children of the axes window. From what I've read in other posts, the way to deal with this is to reorder the array of children.

Comment: That appears to be what `uistack` does, reorder the array of children.

Comment: I took a quick look at the source of uistack and indeed that's what it does. But there are some other "rules" involved as well. As I noted in the comment above, the new image is *not* on top of the previously drawn text objects. In fact, I tried to move the image to the top using `uistack` and it has no effect. So one of the rules apparently is that the image has to be on the bottom of the rendering stack.

Answer (score 0):

AVK probably has a more proper answer than me but I'll post this one anyway.

Its possible to directly replace the data stored in the figure. Poking around a bit in the figure memory you can find where the data is stored and replace it. This code won't resize your figure if the image is larger or smaller than the original.

```
% read some data
h = imshow('ngc6543a.jpg');
text(20,20, 'my text', 'Color', 'red');
text(20,50, 'more text', 'Color', 'blue');

% get a different image
imdata2 = imread('circuit.tif');
height = size(imdata2,1);
width = size(imdata2,2);

% replace the data in the figure
set(h, 'CData', imdata2);
set(h, 'YData', [1 height]);
set(h, 'XData', [1 width]);
```